# Fill outer-circle with Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, graph, svg, drawing, raphael

I’m trying to fill the border of a circle, depending on a variable, like so:

[image] [image]

I found [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/8NZfU/1/) but it’s not what I want. I want the outer border to fill from bottom-up, on both sides of circle.

Here’s the code that I have:

```
var completion = '5%';

drawcircle("js-raphael-completion", completion);

function drawcircle(div, rate) {
  var archtype = Raphael(document.getElementsByClassName(div)[0], "90%", "90%");
  archtype.customAttributes.arc = function (xloc, yloc, value, total, R) {
    var alpha = 360 / total * value,
        a = (90 - alpha) * Math.PI / 180,
        x = xloc + R * Math.cos(a),
        y = yloc - R * Math.sin(a),
        path;
    if (total == value) {
      path = [
          ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
          ["A", R, R, 0, 1, 1, xloc - 0.01, yloc - R]
      ];
    } else {
      path = [
          ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
          ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]
      ];
    }
    return {
       path: path
    };
  };

  // inner ring
  var circle = archtype.circle("50%", "50%", "40%").attr({
      "stroke": "#2787d3",
      "stroke-width": 1
  });

  // text
  var text = archtype.text("95%", "50%", rate).attr({
      'font-size': 14, 'font-family': 'Avenir',
      "fill": "#2787d3"
  });

  // outer ring (filling)
  var my_arc = archtype.path().attr({
      "stroke": "#2787d3",
      "stroke-width": 10,
      arc: [100, 100, 0, 100, 50]
  });

  // animation of outer ring
  my_arc.animate({
     arc: [100, 100, 100, 100, 50]
  }, 1000);
}
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SUBn6/

Currently, because I’m not using percentages for the outer ring (filling), it’s not centred with the border circle (inner).

Another issue I have is with the number “5%”. It needs to follow the outer ring (filling) as it fills up from bottom to top…

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Raphael doesn't have such a settings for stroke ending. So another approach to this would be to have two arcs and fill the space between them to simulate the stroke.

That involves a little more geometry :) but this should work:

```
var completion = '5%';

drawcircle("js-raphael-completion", completion);

// JSFiddle needs not onload
// window.onload = function () {
//  drawcircle("js-raphael-completion", completion);
// };

function drawcircle(div, rate) {
    var archtype = Raphael(document.getElementsByClassName(div)[0], "90%", "90%");
    archtype.customAttributes.arc = function (xloc, yloc, value, total, R,lineWidth) {
        var alpha = 360 / total * value,
            a = value / total * Math.PI,
            w = R * Math.sin(a),
            h = R * Math.cos(a),
            gamma = Math.asin(R / (R + lineWidth) * Math.sin(Math.PI / 2 + a)),
            beta = Math.PI/2 - a - gamma,

            xOffset = (R + lineWidth) * Math.sin(beta) / Math.sin(Math.PI / 2 + a),
            x = xloc - R * Math.sin(a),
            y = yloc + R * Math.cos(a),
            path;

        if (Math.abs(a - Math.PI/2) < 0.0001) {
            xOffset = lineWidth;
        }

        if (total == value) {
            path = [
                ["M", x, y],
                ["A", R , R , 1, 1, 1, x - 0.01, y],
                ["L", x - 0.01,y-lineWidth],
                ["A", R + lineWidth, R + lineWidth, 1, 1, 0, x, y - lineWidth],
                ["Z"]

                /*
                ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
                ["A", R, R, 0, 1, 1, xloc - 0.01, yloc - R]
                */
            ];
        } else {
            path = [
                ["M", x, y],
                ["A", R , R , 0, +(alpha > 180), 0, x + 2 * w, y],
                ["L", x+ 2 * w + xOffset,y],
                ["A", R + lineWidth, R + lineWidth, 0 , +(alpha > 180) , 1, x - xOffset, y],
                ["Z"]
            ];
        }
        return {
            path: path
        };
    };

    // inner ring
    var circle = archtype.circle(100, 100, 50).attr({
        "stroke": "#2787d3",
            "stroke-width": 3
    });

    // text
    var text = archtype.text("95%", "50%", rate).attr({
        'font-size': 14,
        'font-family': 'Avenir',
            "fill": "#2787d3"
    });

    // outer ring (filling)
    var my_arc = archtype.path().attr({
        "stroke": "#FF0000",
        "fill":  "#2787d3",
        "stroke-width" : 0,
        arc: [100, 100, 0, 100, 51,10]
    });

    // animation of outer ring
    my_arc.animate({
        arc: [100, 100, 100, 100, 51,10]
    }, 1000);

}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Xp77x/2/

Answer (score 2):

I think you messed around the cos and sin stuff :). Basically the starting point of the arc is variable depending on the ratio (xloc - R * sin(a), yloc + R * cos(a)), and the width is also variable (2 * R *sin(a)).

I modified a little bit your stuff:

```
var completion = '5%';

drawcircle("js-raphael-completion", completion);

// JSFiddle needs not onload
// window.onload = function () {
//  drawcircle("js-raphael-completion", completion);
// };

function drawcircle(div, rate) {
    var archtype = Raphael(document.getElementsByClassName(div)[0], "90%", "90%");
    archtype.customAttributes.arc = function (xloc, yloc, value, total, R) {
        var alpha = 360 / total * value,
            a = value / total * Math.PI,
            w = R * Math.sin(a),
            h = R * Math.cos(a),
            x = xloc - R * Math.sin(a),
            y = yloc + R * Math.cos(a),
            path;

        if (total == value) {
            path = [
                ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
                ["A", R, R, 0, 1, 1, xloc - 0.01, yloc - R]
            ];
        } else {
            path = [
                ["M", x, y],
                ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 0, x + 2 * w, y]
            ];
        }
        return {
            path: path
        };
    };

    // inner ring
    var circle = archtype.circle(100, 100, 50).attr({
        "stroke": "#2787d3",
            "stroke-width": 1
    });

    // text
    var text = archtype.text("95%", "50%", rate).attr({
        'font-size': 14,
        'font-family': 'Avenir',
            "fill": "#2787d3"
    });

    // outer ring (filling)
    var my_arc = archtype.path().attr({
        "stroke": "#2787d3",
            "stroke-width": 10,
        arc: [100, 100, 0, 100, 50]
    });

    // animation of outer ring
    my_arc.animate({
        arc: [100, 100, 100, 100, 55]
    }, 1000);
}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/Xp77x/1/

However I used absolute coordinates. To have relative coordinates you need to parse a little bit the input for % and translate this to a 0-100 canvas.

Comment: Thanks for this. A couple of issues.When the outer circle starts filling, there is some overlap with the inner circle. But this is fixed near the end (top): http://oi41.tinypic.com/x0occ0.jpg. And the second issue is more Raphael related. Is it possible to make the path fill horizontally instead of rotating around the circle? It’s kinda hard to explain (see screenshot above)… Like if you were filling that empty border with liquid…